# Issue with high server load centos

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, cgi

I'm having some major issues with one of my servers.

Server load is extremely high: load average: 142.28, 144.80, 139.6

The server is running Centos 6 and has a Perl image sharing script running on it. The server has moderate traffic but for some reason the load is extremely high.

Running iotop I see just a bunch of httpd requests but there's no iowait or problems with disc R/W.

Running the top command there's lots of CGI Zombie processes that are all "Defunct". I'm not sure how to handle them because I've set keepalive to off to prevent something like this from occurring.

I need some advise. I've looked at many questions on here and I'm not sure what to do. I've installed CSF and configured it to block possible DDOS attacks. I've also installed mod_evasive.

The server's obviously super sluggish. Any advise would be appreciated.

**Edited**

Running netstat -an | wc -l shows 13132 connections.

Comment: If a parent isn't reaping its children, you can get rid of the zombies by killing that parent. If the parent is PID 1, you'll have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Scientific Method

- Install monitoring.
- Gather data.
- Analyze data.
- Make decisions.
- Make changes.
- Monitor changes.